# Questions on Vedanta Philosophy

Tags: vedanta, advaita, rig-veda, adi-shankaracharya

1. Advaita Vedanta does talk about one reality (Brahman) becomes many in the form of universe. Is there any explanation on why does one indivisible brahman becomes many?
2. If one appearing as many is just an illusion of our mind, then why does the illusion itself gets created? What is that initial trigger which caused Brahman to take form?